# Set the latest date value to the Quick Filter in TABLEAU

Tags: tableau-desktop

There is a *live* worksheet called Person with columns - Names & Birthdays. Need to create a quick filter with a default value pointing to the latest birthday.

For example: If there are 3 Records as follows,

> Names  Birthdays
>   A      8/9/1993
>   S      6/5/1994
>   Z      8/15/2000

The filter should hold the default value 8/15/2000 in it with other values unchecked in the drop down list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I see what you are asking. When you add your filter click the little drop down arrow in the filter --> edit filter-->select the tab labeled "Top"--> by field radio button==>Top from the first drop down-->enter 1 in the next field which will say by after it-->select birthday from the next drop down--then maximum. This will change the view to show only the most recent birthdate. Hope  this helps.

Comment: My Quick_Filter is of type "MULTI-VALUES-DROP-DOWN" and it shows "ALL" like how I had before

Comment: Do you want to either a) always filter to data rows with the latest Birthday only or b) show the latest birthday only by default, but show a filter that allows people to pick additional or alternate dates as well?

Comment: @alex option b is what I exactly wanted (Show latest birthday only by default, but show a filter that allows people to pick additional or alternate dates). As of now, I'm able to filter data with latest birthday only and it is not showing any other birthdays even when the corresponding check boxes are checked

Answer (score 0):

Tableau currently doesn't give you dynamic control over quick filter defaults. For dates. They generally start out with the settings that were published.

Here are a few easy suggestions that are similar to, but not exactly, what you want. At the end, there is a way to do exactly what you want at the cost of more effort.

For **continuous** **date** fields, you can set the filter to show **Relative Dates** and the filter allows the user to easily set a range of dates showing the last N days, weeks or months relative to an anchor date. The anchor date defaults to the current date.

For **discrete date** fields, you can display a top filter as tia97 recommended, and show an integer valued parameter control to allow the user to pick N to see the latest N birthdays. (i.e. the N youngest people)

You could try other variations using parameters, calculated fields and quick filters, but it might be simpler to just show the list of birthdates and let people choose.

Finally, if you are publishing this workbook to Tableau Server, you can use the Javascript API to control the filtering user experience yourself. You can embed the Tableau visualization in a web page, surrounded by custom HTML, CSS and Javascript that you define. Build whatever controls you want for user interaction, and then send JavaScript commands to Tableau to direct the filter actions. More effort, but you get a lot more control over the UX.

Generally, I'd use the builtin features in Tableau Desktop as far as they go to get most of your desired UX quickly and easily, and then save the JavaScript API work for final polish on only your most public visualizations that really need it.